# Make NERDTree and CtrlP ignore top-level vendor directory

Tags: vim

I would like both NERDTree and CtrlP to ignore (not display and not index) the top-level vendor directory.

However, I do want both of these plugins (and anything else in the future) to consider files that are under a vendor directory not at the top-level of the project (e.g app/assets/javascripts/vendor).

My wildignore setting is the following:

`wildignore+=*.o,*.obj,.git,*.rbc,*.class,.svn,coverage/*,vendor`

And that makes the vendor directory ignored wherever it may be.

Can you recommend a solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your .vimrc:

```
let g:NERDTreeRespectWildIgnore = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

For NERDTree, you need to add that to `g:NERDTreeIgnore`:

```
:let g:NERDTreeIgnore=['\~$', 'vendor']
```

Since I don't like to maintain the exclusion list in both `'wildignore'` and NERDTree, I use the following scriptlet to automatically set the latter from the former:

```
" Use the 'wildignore' and 'suffixes' settings for filtering out files.
function! s:FileGlobToRegexp( glob )
    " The matching is done against the sole file / directory name.
    if a:glob =~# '^\*\.'
        return '\.' . a:glob[2:] . '$'
    else
        return '^' . a:glob . '$'
    endif
endfunction
function! s:SuffixToRegexp( suffix )
    return escape(v:val, '.~') . "$"
endfunction
let g:NERDTreeIgnore =
\   map(split(&wildignore, ','), 's:FileGlobToRegexp(v:val)') +
\   map(split(&suffixes, ','), 's:SuffixToRegexp(v:val)')
delfunction s:SuffixToRegexp
delfunction s:FileGlobToRegexp
```

---

**Edit**

However, that will *globally* filter out the `vendor` directory. Doing that only for the toplevel is not currently possible, as NERDTree executes the filter comparison against the file's basename only:

```
self.getLastPathComponent(0) =~# pat
```

Comment: Thanks for the script but I'm not sure this is what I need. I want vendor to be ignored on the top-level but not below. To give a concrete example, in Rails projects, there is a top-level vendor dir that contains all the dependencies that I want ignored. There can also  be a vendor folder in app/assets/javascripts/vendor which I want NERDTree to show and CtrlP to index.

Comment: Like `'wildignore'`, the NERDTree option is global, too (see my edit). You'd have to modify the plugin to get what you want.

Comment: See also [NERDTreeRespectWildIgnore](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/eee431d/doc/NERD_tree.txt#L636)